# Authorize attribute is letting ActionResult code execute

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, authorization, actionresult

I have a custom attribute that I am using for Ajax requests to prevent the default FormsAuthentication workflow from happening (since it doesn't make sense for an Ajax request).

This is the custom authorize attribute:

```
public class AjaxAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute {
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        UrlHelper urlHelper;

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            //Don't let IIS7 be mean.
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            //Return JSON which tells the client where the login page exists if the user wants to authenticate.
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                new {
                    LoginUrl = string.Format("{0}?ReturnURL={1}", FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl, urlHelper.Encode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery))
                }
            ));
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
        } else {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

I have my ActionResult decorated with the custom authorize attribute like so:

```
[HttpPut]
[ValidateInput(false)]
[AjaxAuthorize]
public ActionResult Comment(string id, string comment) {
    //stuff happens here.
}
```

An exception is thrown inside of my action result because I try to access information about a user that would only exist if you are logged in.  But, I don't understand why this code is even being executed because I have my authorization attribute protecting the action.

Comment: I know its a very old thread but did you find answer.

Comment: @BhargavKonda Yes please see the answer I posted to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up returning an HTTP 418 (I have been wanting to use this for awhile) so that the Forms Authentication module didn't intercept the request.  Then in my script I look for that status code and handle it as an unauthorized request and do the proper redirect.

Comment: I used 419 Authentication Timeout (not in RFC 2616).  This helped put me on right track.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) 
{
    // Returns HTTP 401 - see comment in HttpUnauthorizedResult.cs. 
    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
```

This is default implementation of HandleUnauthorizedRequest. Probably you need to assign your custom ActionResult that contains JSON you need and valid status code. I'm not sure direct processing request object from HTTP context would work.

Comment: The existing `AuthorizeCore` is already returning false since the user is not authenticated.

Comment: Sorry, answer was edited. Previous answer version contained assumption AuthorizeCode method returns true.

Comment: How do I stop the forms authentication module from kicking in?  I just want to return JSON, not do a redirect to the login page.

Comment: Try to turn it off in web.config.

Comment: I may not have made the question clear enough.  I want the redirect to happen, just not for XML HTTP Requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);` inside the IF block. Or just remove the ELSE block and always call `base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);`.

Comment: It's not the answer you may be looking for, but I would try starting this method again, calling only the base method and then, step by step, debug and add your code to identify exactly which command is causing it to fail.